# Android application: how to use the camera and grab the image bytes?

Tags: java, android, mobile, titanium

I'm trying to create a small app for Android that takes a picture using the device's camera and put's a PNG frame on top of it. This way the final saved picture will have a beach on top of it, or hats, or anything. Does anyone have any sample programs with this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the SDK documentation on using the image capture intent [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents).

I start my image capture intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE is a private member in my activity:

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
```

Then get the byte array back from the camera by using the following onActivityResult handler:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {        
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            AddImage(byteArray);

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }               
}
```

After that you can do all the processing you want on the image.

Comment: How to process the image? Which lib should i use?

Comment: I know this question is answered but this will only retrieve the thumbnail image not the full picture.