# Using the Camera in my app.

Tags: java, android, camera

I've tried to start the camera and use it my app - with unsatisfactory results. I followed the sample code provided in the android SDK (the Preview class), and I got bad results - the camera was rotating and when I tried to add a button, it never showed up.

I checked other apps and it looks like the skype app uses the same camera app as the one built into the phone. I want to know how I can implement this in my own app. Any solutions?

Comment: That's a very broad question. Did you try Google already? I quickly found two helpful URL's: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027695/android-application-how-to-use-the-camera-and-grab-the-image-bytes. Please check those first.